# Is trace of regular representation in Lie group a delta function?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

My major is physics. I need to use some tools in group theory, but I am really 
confused by the trace in compact infinite groups. The following is my question:

In discrete group theory, the irreducible representation of identity group element $e$ is always an identity matrix. So the trace of $e$ under 
regular representation is the order of the group : $\chi(e) = |G|$. I hope to get 
similar result for Lie group. For example, SO(2) has infinite number of irreducible representations, $D^{(m)}$, where $m=0,\pm 1, \pm 2,\cdots $.
All of them are 1-dimensional $D^{(m)} = e^{im\phi}$. Here $\phi$ is the rotation angle. For element $R(\phi)$ in SO(2), the trace in $m$th irreducible representation should be 
$\chi(R(\phi))=e^{im\phi}$, if we sum all these traces up, we get the trace in regular representation. So what is the trace of $e$ in the regular representation ? It seems to be infinite.

Comment: I think I remember $\sum_{V\in G^\wedge}(\dim V)\int_G f(g)\chi_V(g)\,{\rm d}g=f(e)$ being true for compact $G$ (normalized Haar measure). Of course for finite $G$, indeed $\int_G f(g)\chi_{\rm reg}(g)\,{\rm d}g=f(e)$ is true.

Comment: Your question on MO was moved here already (you can find it at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232328/is-trace-of-regular-representation-in-lie-group-a-delta-function)

Comment: The simple answer is that there is no trace. You are trying to compute something that simply does not make sense.

Comment: @whacka Thanks for your reply. I think my question is not clear, so I rephrased it just now. If you have time, could you have a look ?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks. I did not realize I have two copies now. Sorry to create this redundancy.

Comment: I will close this one. I suggest you edit the old one if you want to change it.