# Is trace of regular representation in Lie group a delta function?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

My major is physics. I need to use some tools in group theory, but I am really 
confused by the trace in compact infinite groups. The following is my question:

In discrete group theory, the irreducible representation of identity group element $e$ is always an identity matrix. So the trace of $e$ under 
regular representation is the order of the group : $\chi(e) = |G|$. I hope to get 
similar result for Lie group. For example, SO(2) has infinite number of irreducible representations, $D^{(m)}$, where $m=0,\pm 1, \pm 2,\cdots $.
All of them are 1-dimensional $D^{(m)} = e^{im\phi}$. Here $\phi$ is the rotation angle. For element $R(\phi)$ in SO(2), the trace in $m$th irreducible representation should be 
$\chi(R(\phi))=e^{im\phi}$, if we sum all these traces up, we get the trace in regular representation. So what is the trace of $e$ in the regular representation ? It seems to be infinite.

Comment: I don't think that this is appropriate for MO, but it also doesn't seem to merit a downvote—it's a legitimate, if not research-level, question, and subtle for someone not used to these concerns.

Comment: This is the first website that Google recommended to me for math questions. I am a newbie to representation theory, I tried to do some reading, but mathematical group books are too hard for me.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the answer and the above website. Appreciate !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you implicitly observe, there is no well defined notion of the trace of *this particular* infinite-dimensional matrix.  (There *is* a class of (infinite-dimensional) matrices to which one can assign traces, inventively called trace class (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class), but there are no infinite-dimensional unitary matrices among them.)  Notice that the statement that there is no trace is different to the statement that the trace is infinite.  For example, the regular representation of $S^1$ on itself may be diagonalised so that the image of $z$ is the matrix $(z^n[n = m])_{m, n \in \mathbb Z}$, and there's no reasonable answer for the sum $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} z^n$ that doesn't make some assumptions that will destroy the nice invariance properties that we'd like a trace to have.

What one may do instead is to remember that the *scalar* character is just the trace of the *distribution* character, in the sense that $\operatorname{tr} \int \pi(g)f(g)\mathrm dg = \int \Theta_\pi(g)f(g)\mathrm dg$ for $f \in C^\infty(G)$ and $\pi$ an irreducible (finite-dimensional) representation of the compact Lie group $G$, where $\mathrm dg$ is a Haar measure on $G$; and one may ask about the *distribution* character of the regular representation.  This *is* the $\delta$ distribution at the identity, in the sense that $$\sum_{\pi \in \hat G} \operatorname{deg}(\pi)\operatorname{tr} \int \pi(g)f(g)\mathrm dg = f(e)$$ (if $\mathrm dg$ is normalised to give $G$ total mass $1$).  This is known as the Plancherel theorem.

EDIT:  The original version of my second paragraph directly contradicted the first, by (inadvertently) not really speaking of the distribution character at all.  The reason that I prefer to work *via* this roundabout approach of looking for a scalar function representing the distribution character $f \mapsto \int \pi(g)f(g)\mathrm dg$, rather than just taking the trace of $\pi(g)$ as one is used to doing, is precisely because it handes the infinite-dimensional case with *élan*.  This is particularly important in the theory of non-compact groups, which may not even *have* any finite-dimensional representations.

Comment: And the reason $\sum \deg(\pi)\pi(g)$ is relevant is because heuristically it "is" the trace of the regular representation, in view of the Peter-Weyl theorem.

Comment: @whacka, thanks for (implicitly) prompting me to go back and look at what I'd written.  Of course $\sum \operatorname{deg}(\pi)\pi(g)$ doesn't directly make any sense as written (although I agree that its trace is 'morally' the trace of the regular representation).  I think that all is in order now.